# Mailslot blocking forever

Tags: delphi, ipc, mailslot

I decided to use mailslot for IPC. On windows 8 everything works fine. But on Windows Xp I receive fine first message but then the call to ReadFile gets stuck.

Here is my test code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hand : THandle;
  buf : array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
  btsRead : DWORD;
begin
  hand := CreateMailslot('\\.\mailslot\somemailslot', 255, DWORD(-1), nil);
  if hand <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
      while True do
      begin
        ReadFile(hand, buf, 255, btsRead, nil); // call gets stuck after first message
        ShowMessage(buf);
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end;
  end;
```

On Windows 8 I continue to receive messages from client application, but on windows xp the call to ReadFile blocks forever waiting for a message. I tried reopening client application without success.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your third parameter is set to -1, which means `MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER `.  If there is no message, it will block. Are you sure one is being sent?  You restart the client, but what is the server doing?  (Btw, looping and calling `Application.ProcessMessages` is horrendous design - if this is anything other than a test app, can you structure it a different way?)

Comment: Have you checked what says `GetMailslotInfo` before you try to read that second message ?

Comment: Have a look at MSDN's example: [Reading from a Mailslot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365785.aspx).  It uses `GetMailslotInfo()` to determine if there are messages waiting, and then uses `ReadFile()` with overlapped I/O to read them.  You can alternatively set the `lReadTimeout` parameter of `CreateMailslot()` to anything other than `MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER` (-1) so that a blocking `ReadFile()` will eventually timeout and exit if no message arrives within the timeout period.

Comment: Also, how is the server sending messages?  And are they always 255 bytes in size?

Comment: The client is sending 255 byte messages but they never get received. Why should I use diffrent approach when this works just fine and is documented in msdn. Also @DavidM is just a test code and is nothing wrong with it

Comment: Hold on - the client is sending? That terminology is confusing; I had thought the client was listening, and so the above was client-side code. But: how do you *know* the client is sending?

Comment: And if it's test code, ok, just making sure you know something is wrong with it and not to do it in real code.

Answer (score 2):

Use a thread for reading from the mailslot. Otherwise you'll always have the problem that you'd have to process Windows messages while you're waiting in ReadFile.

Now having said that, the calls to CreateMailslot and ReadFile look very similar to what I use (on XP and above) except that I have a larger buffer (65535).

If neither of these helps then the problem is probably somewhere else.

When you need to cancel the call to ReadFile, call `CloseHandle(hand)` from the main thread. That is useful when you need to exit the thread. This is another reason for using a thread for the mailslot.

Comment: I will try in diffrent thread, tought at this too. I will share u the results.